# Can I publish actions on objects not owned by me

Tags: facebook-opengraph

I am creating a movie timeline app with custom actions "Watching" but I want to use objects from imdb.com website.

Is this scenario supported? Do these objects must reside under my website?

Comment: Did you happen to ... ask them for permission to do so?

Answer (score 1):

That's possible.
Add the built-in watch action and movie object to your app and post to /me/video.watches with movie=http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0499549/ (example URL)
But at the end Facebook needs to check/approve your concept...

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible as long as the action you're posting can be attached to the object type specified at the third party URL.

However, im not sure why you'd want to do this. Publishing an action to IMDB (for example) means friends of the user who published the story will end up on IMDB, not your app. But its your call...